# How can I read and interpret old Danish script?

Tags: palaeography, transcriptions, denmark, baptism-records

Normally I take script and put it into Google Translate. The problem is I can't read this script. It is legible however, this baptismal record is from 1706 and I don't have any experience with really old Danish handwriting.

If you think you can help or know someone that speaks Danish, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you add a link to the document?

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend:

http://www.danishmuseum.org/research-and-translation.cfm

"Genealogy Center translators are able to translate most Danish letters and documents, including those in old Gothic handwriting or print, as well as Danish church and census records; and can make referrals for translations of both modern and Gothic German-language documents."

Answer (score 3):

You could try the Danish Society for computer assisted genealog (DIS-Danmark) at https://www.slaegtogdata.dk/

English starter help for their forums here: https://www.slaegtogdata.dk/andet/forum-help-english

Comment: If it's a short text and the source is available online you could perhaps link it and we could give it a go...

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to learn to more about Danish and Scandinavian handwriting yourself. At a minimum, you'll get a little further with the records before needing to ask for help, and can be more specific about the problem words.

The [FamilySearch Wiki](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Main_Page) has a number of pages and tutorials on Scandinavian languages and writing. Search word combinations like Danish, handwriting.

Their tutorials are definitely worthwhile, regardless of existing experience with a language.