# What tools can be used to translate handwritten Danish documents?

Tags: death-records, translation, denmark

[image: Death Notice for Michael Sorensen]

Can someone help me translate this Danish death notice?

It's for my Great grandfather. I am trying to trace his parents.

https://www.danishfamilysearch.com/sogn438/churchbook/source27353/opslag5509650

My great grandfather's entry on Wikitree: https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Sorenson-616

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  If you need more information about the way the site works, you can find it in the [help] or ask a question in the companion [Meta]. I've shortened your question title so it will better fit our site guidelines. Can you tell us where you found this death notice? A source citation helps us when we analyze the source for the quality of the information it contains.

Comment: Is this the same death notice which is transcribed and translated on the linked WikiTree page?

Comment: Yes, thanks Jan, I used your tools below to do the translation myself.

Comment: Here at Stack Exchange, it's okay -- in fact, it's encouraged -- to post an answer to your own question as a means of sharing your research. Could you post an answer to your question so other people can see you were able to translate the notice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading and interpreting baptismal record (from 1706) in old Danish script?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5523/reading-and-interpreting-baptismal-record-from-1706-in-old-danish-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of the links that were shared and Google Translate, I was able to translate the record as follows:

**Death Notice in Danish:** Forhenværende husejer af Vennebjerg, Vennebjerg, sogn. Fodt i Haage, Vennebjerg sogn d 26 Marts 1859. Hjemme døbt d 13 April 1859. Fremstillet I Vennebjerg kirke d 31 Juli 1859. Son of this mand Soren Mouritsen og husten Johanne Marie Sorensen fra haage. Enkemand after Ane Sophie Hansen der dode i December 1923. Sidste fælles Bopæl: haage

**Death Notice in English:** Former homeowner of Vennebjerg, Vennebjerg, parish. Born in Haage, Vennebjerg parish d, March 26, 1859. Home baptized d April 13, 1859. Produced in Vennebjerg church on July 31, 1859. Son of this man Soren Mouritsen and his wife Johanne Marie Sorensen from haage. Single man after Ane Sophie Hansen who died in December 1923. Last joint residence: haage.

Answer (score 4):

This is a stub of an answer, but here are some resources that can help you get started.

From the FamilySearch Research Wiki:

- [Danish Genealogical Word List](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Danish_Genealogical_Word_List)
- [Denmark Record Finder](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Denmark_Record_Finder) (to find other records which may have his parents

FamilySearch also has resources for Denmark and Danish records in the [Help Center Lessons](https://www.familysearch.org/ask/landing?search=danish&show=all). You can search by going to the main FamilySearch screen and clicking on Help in the upper right corner, then choosing Help Center from the drop-down menu.